# Login form is getting expired while automating login feature

Tags: java, selenium

Have you guys faced problem like login form is getting expired while automating the login script but  when i do login manually login works pretty good!

I am fetching url and credentials from db!

Comment: Can you provide some more details here? What do you mean when you say "getting expired", what is actually happening here that indicates to you that it has expired? Can you provide a sample of the code you are using, or possibly the URL to the page you are trying to automate so that we can reproduce the issue?